# How to specialize a templatized class for taking a method function type that takes no parameters?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Caller{};

template<typename T, typename RET> 
class Caller<T, RET()>  {}

template<typename T, typename RET, typename HEAD, typename TAIL>
class Caller<T, RET(HEAD,TAIL...)> : Caller<T, RET(TAIL...)> {}

class MyClass { void foo(int,int){}};

Caller<decltype(&MyClass::foo), decltype(&MyClass::foo)> caller();
```

I want this code to hit the third definition twice, then the second definition once.

I've tried many variations on this and it either seems to jump right to the top-most one or complain about not enough or too many template types.

Comment: I think I was close but needed to put the object type in the function template bit.. like <T, RET(MyClass::*)(HEAD, TAIL...)> but I'm still working on making sure that's right

Comment: Yes, that is the answer.   I'll update this question with an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't picking up the specialization because it wasn't specialized as an object method.   You have to have `void(ClassType::*)(int,int)` for it to be an object method.

```
template<typename A>
class Thing<RET(A::*)()> {
public:
    Thing(int a){printf("In 2\n");}
};

template<typename A, typename RET, typename HEAD, typename... TAIL>
class Thing<RET(A::*)(HEAD, TAIL...)> : Thing<RET(A::*)(TAIL...)> {
public:
    Thing(int a) : Thing<RET(A::*)(TAIL...)>(a){printf("In 3\n");}

};

class MyClass {public: void foo(int a,int b){}};

// this will print 2, 3, 3
Thing<decltype(&MyClass::foo)> thing(1);
```